# Список из центра отрезков python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Например, есть число 4. То нужно получить список подобный [0,4,2,1,3] если число 6 то [0,6,3,1,4,2,5] то есть центры половин отрезков (пример для 4: первые два числа - начало и конец, а затем 4/2=2 2/2=1 1+2=3)
Может кто знает как программу написать?

Comment: Задача простая. Многие, кто является непосредственным участником этого ресурса, смогут её решить. Ответ: да! Безусловно, Здесь многие знают, как программу написать. Надеюсь, я утолил жажду вашего любопытства.

Comment: Для 6 как получается?

Comment: Задача непростая, поскольку может быть число 140, например и тд
А для 6 аналогично, 2 и 5 в конце как остаточные числа. Не знаю как это можно реализовать в виде алгоритма, учитывая что числа могут быть разные. И 16 и 250 и дт